# Move into a function that takes const lvalue reference

Tags: c++, c++11, move, move-semantics, rvalue

I am using this class, not written by me and I can't change its code:

```
class A {
private:
    Val d_val;
public:
    void setVal(const Val& val) { d_val = val; }
    const Val& getVal() const { return d_val; }
};
```

`Val` supports move but class `A` was written without that in mind. Can I somehow avoid a copy of `val` in the scenario? I doubt `std::move(val)` into `setVal` will work since it doesn't take an r value reference.

```
A a;
Val val;
// populate val
a.setVal(val); // I don't need val after here
```

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot move from a `const` object. That's why Herb Sutter suggested " want speed? pass by value". With that constructor, you cannot avoid a copy construction or copy assignment

Answer (score 0):

The declarations in class A clearly state that getVal shall not modify the object and that the returned reference should not be used to change its pointee either, so you are not allowed to use that in a move.

That being said, as `d_val` is not declared as const, you could use a const-cast to remove constness on the reference, but you must know that it is bad and should be avoided.

That being said, you cannot use `setVal` if you want a move assignement, but you can manually generate the move:

```
A a;
Val val;
// populate val

Val& av = const_cast<Val &>(a.getVal()); // cheating compiler...
av = std::move(val);
```

Comment: I don't understand how a const cast would work, I can't change the code of `A`.